# How to make a comparison for the record that has rows to another rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have first table that has columns:

```
   1. id
   2. key
   3. value
```

And second table(more like the list):

```
   key
```

I need to get distinct id that contains all keys from second table

I have tried self join but it is very slow. Also I tried COUNT = COUNT but  performance the same.

Self join:

```sql
select  f.id from first
    join first f2 on f.id = f2.id AND f2.key  = f. key
```

COUNT:

```sql
select a.keyfrom @a a
    where ( select SUM(CASE WHEN k.[key] is not NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) from [b] b
        LEFT JOIN Second s on s.key= b.[Key]
     where b.[Key] = a.key) = @KeyCount
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will greatly help us here.

Comment: So your 2nd table lists all possible keys that an entity in Table 1 may have?

Comment: It would help if your query samples would compile, but sadly, both don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check this-

```
SELECT A.id
FROM TAB1 A
INNER JOIN TAB2 B ON A.[key] = B.[Key]
GROUP BY A.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT A.[key]) 
    = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Key]) FROM TAB2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your case resolve my problem.

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat of a stab in the dark, but perhaps this is what you're after...?

```
SELECT I.ID
FROM TableB B
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT ca.ID
                  FROM dbo.TableA ca) I
     LEFT JOIN TableA A ON B.[key] = A.[key]
                       AND I.ID = A.ID
GROUP BY I.ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN A.[Key] IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd3f5fda68a405d9d2828d0c5c92cfdc)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- Your 2nd table lists all possible keys, and
- Your first table (containing entity IDs, keys, and key values) can only contain 1 entity-key combination,

something like this may work:

```
SELECT [id], COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [id]
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM keys)
```

Now with some sample data. Assume the following keys:

```
+--------+----------+
| key_id | key_name |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Key1     |
|      2 | Key2     |
|      3 | Key3     |
+--------+----------+
```

And the following entities:

```
+----+-----+-------+
| id | key | value |
+----+-----+-------+
|  1 |   1 |     1 |
|  1 |   2 |     2 |
|  1 |   3 |     3 |
|  2 |   2 |     2 |
|  2 |   3 |     3 |
+----+-----+-------+
```

Assume how Entity 1 has all keys, but Entity 2 is missing Key 1. So, as expected, the query returns only Entity 1.

Comment: Yes, this  is work, but I forgot to mention that there is the case when key has a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation for the counting:

```
select f.id
from first f
where exists (select 1 from second s where s.key = f.key)
group by f.id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from second);
```

This assumes that there are no duplicates in the table.  It also assumes that extra keys in `first` are ok.  If not, use `left join`:

```
select f.id
from first f left join
     second s
     on s.key = f.key
group by f.id
having count(s.key) = (select count(*) from second) and
       count(*) = count(s.key);
```